# AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat looping animation using callback

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, animatedvectordrawable

I'm trying to implement an animation in my Android app using AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat, for compatibility for API >= 21.

I want the animation to loop for the duration of the Activity. I'm able to play the animation, and it will also loop fine on API >= 25. But when I run it on devices or emulators with API 21 through 24 I only see the animation once. If I set a breakpoint inside the callback method, I see that it executes the callback too, but the animation does not repeat.

I find that the animation is running on a different thread, as it does not block UI.

This is the method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
    final AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat anim = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.avd_pass_inside);

    imageView.setImageDrawable(anim);

    anim.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {

            anim.start();
        }
    });
    anim.start();
}
```

From what I read, using the Compat library should make this work for all API levels from 14 and up, but I don't even have to go there, as the rest of my app has requirements that puts it at mimimum 21.

Is there some (preferably non-hacky :) ) way to make this work consistently across these API levels? Is it a bug? Did I miss something?

Comment: Not a single comment? *tumbleweed*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can see this is a subtle difference between the system & compat versions. Compat seems to call the callback before its animations have been flagged as having ended. So the call to `start()` is ignored because it thinks it hasn't ended.

The solution is the usual hack: post a `Runnable` to start it when the animations have finished.

```
new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
  @NonNull
  private final Handler fHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(@NonNull Drawable drawable) {
    Animatable2Compat avd = (Animatable2Compat) drawable;
    fHandler.post(avd::start);
  }
};
```