# Different AnimatedVectorDrawable on Marshmallow (shapeshifter animation, androidx involved)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

My animation code is crashing. It's the animation created from xml:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    //not relevant
</animated-vector>
```

Code that runs the animation and crashes:

```
val animationDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.anim_logbook_register_measurement)

    val callback = object : Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
        override fun onAnimationStart(drawable: Drawable?) {
            super.onAnimationStart(drawable)
            //not relevant
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable) {
            //not relevant
        }
    }

    AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.registerAnimationCallback(animationDrawable, callback)
    animationCallback = callback
    (animationDrawable as? Animatable)?.start()
```

Crash occurs on line`AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.registerAnimationCallback(animationDrawable, callback)` and here is the reason:

```
android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable cannot be cast to androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat
```

Looks like `ContextCompat.getDrawable` on Android 6 creates non-androidx `AnimatedVectorDrawable` while `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat .registerAnimationCallback` expects androidx one and crashes. It gets obvious when looking inside `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat`:

```
public static void registerAnimationCallback(Drawable dr,
        Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback callback) {
    if (dr == null || callback == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(dr instanceof Animatable)) {
        return;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        registerPlatformCallback((AnimatedVectorDrawable) dr, callback);
    } else {
        ((AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) dr).registerAnimationCallback(callback);
    }
}
```

Looks line Android bug to me, anyone aware of this? Is there a way that would work on all versions starting from 5?

Comment: use this if statment  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)     and make it so that if the device is a certain verison you run your animation code and if it is smaller than a certain version you run the animation code for older versions...albiet a work around....you just gonna have to code a second line of animation code for older sdks

Comment: I couldn't find equivalent of registerAnimationCallback.

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/re-animation-7869722af206     This might help It is for animation on older devices

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297753/animatedvectordrawablecompat-looping-animation-using-callback      This one aswell

Answer (score 0):

This is awful but apparently it works if I load drawable from xml like this:

```
val animationDrawable = return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.anim_logbook_register_measurement)
    } else {
        AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.anim_logbook_register_measurement)
    }
```